# Regex is not correctly applied as I try to rewrite the snippet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the following code, which involves some pre-processing on the code into a pre-processing code that uses pandas.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # extracting field names through first row
    fields = csvreader.next()

    # extracting each data row one by one
    for row in csvreader:
        title.append(row[25])
        line = re.sub(r'[.,"!]+', '', row[25], flags=re.MULTILINE)  # removes the characters specified
        line = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # removes RT
        line = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # remove link
        line = re.sub(r'[:]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        line=(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", line,flags=re.MULTILINE))
        line = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, line)  # filter non-ascii characers
        synopses.append(line)
```

Now, using the pandas library. I translated the above code as follows:

```
input_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"]

input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(lambda str : re.sub(r'[.,"!]+', '', str, flags=re.MULTILINE))
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(lambda str : re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', str, flags=re.MULTILINE))
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(lambda str : re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', str, flags=re.MULTILINE))
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(lambda str : re.sub(r'[:]+', '', str, flags=re.MULTILINE))
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(lambda str : re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", str,flags=re.MULTILINE))
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(lambda str : filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, str))

print(input_posts)
```

The issue is that the final column in `input_posts` still consists of `https://...` URLs, although I have tried to remove them. Also, I am not sure if this is the best way to translate code using pandas where I have used multiple lambda functions. Is there something wrong in the regex applied / or sequence in which the regex is applied?

**Example of expected output:**

> @PRNcnsmr: SK-II unveils bold and unfiltered take on beauty with its
>   first ever #BareSkinProject with @ChloeGMoretz https://abc

need to remove https://abc link to get

> @PRNcnsmr: SK-II unveils bold and unfiltered take on beauty with its
>   first ever #BareSkinProject with @ChloeGMoretz

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Rakesh For an input like `RT @PRNcnsmr: SK-II unveils bold and unfiltered take on beauty with its first ever #BareSkinProject with @ChloeGMoretz https://abc` need to remove `https://abc` link

Answer (score 0):

You're applying each transform to `input_data["Post Data"]`, instead you probably need to do `input_data = input_data.apply(...)` for every transform after the first one:

```
input_posts = input_data["Post Data"].apply(...)
input_posts = input_posts.apply(...)
...
```